# Calibration and consistency for predictions over time

Tags: forecasting, calibration

It's common to plot the predicted probability of some event/events versus the actual fraction of such events that happened to obtain a calibration curve showing whether the predictions were under or overconfident.

I would like to do the same thing with predictions which update and change over time. For example, 538 frequently updates their estimated probabilities over time in response to new evidence. Similarly, prediction markets offer a way to trace the probability of certain events over time based on the frequently changing price of some contract.

The idea is that if the probability of some event is predicted to be 1%, then the next day it's updated to 50% -- well, this should happen at most for 1/50 events, and it seems like fairly strong evidence that either the original estimation was overconfident or the updated estimate is underconfident. On the other hand, suppose that in many occasions, if the probability is updated from 25% to 30%, then the next day it never fails to reach 35%, then that seems like evidence that either 35% is too high or 30% is too low.

So my question is: Given some sequences of probabilities $p^i_1, p^i_2, \ldots p^i_n$ and the final outcome $x^i$ ($i$ indexes the multiple sequences/events), is there some way to gauge the calibration and/or self-consistency of these predictions?

---

Here are my idea so far..

If a sequence of probabilities is self-consistent, then it must be the case that $p_i = E[p_j]$ for $i < j$. Let intervals $S_i$ partition the unit interval and $l_i$ be their lower bounds. Then $p_i \geq \sum_k Pr(p_j \in S_k) l_k \geq Pr(p_j \in S) l$ for any arbitrary *single* interval S. Setting $S = (m p_i, 1)$ gives us $Pr(p_j > m p_i) \leq \frac{1}{m}$, which formalizes my earlier thoughts about going from 1% to 50%.

My first thought was to map each sequence of probabilities to a large number of (prediction, result) pairs which could be used with any "ordinary" calibration method. For example, predicting 1% of the event at time $i$ would be mapped to predicting that $p_j \geq 50\%$ happens with probability $2\%$ for all $j > i$. However this doesn't quite work because I only have an inequality, not an equality.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "[t]he idea is that if the probability of some event is predicted to be 1%, then the next day it's updated to 50% -- well, this should happen at most for 1/50 events"